# Bootstrap 4 popover a div

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, popover

I want to show on click a button popover a div on top. And click outside hide.
HTML:

```
<button class="pop-show" type="button">Show</button>

<div class="pop-inn">
    <p>content</p>
    <h5><img src="img.png" alt="image">Candidate</h5>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    // Enables popover
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you want the contents of the `pop-inn` div to be what is displayed in the popover when you click the button?

So there are a few things I have changed in the working snippet below.  First off, for a popover to be able to be dismissed when clicking outside of it, it must be an `<a>` tag, not a `<button>`, but you can style links as buttons (which is why I added the `btn btn-primary` classes.)

Then I passed a bunch of options to the `.popover()` method.

1. `html: true` tells it that it is displaying html, not plain text.
2. `trigger: 'focus'` tells it to dismiss the popover when you click outside it.
3. `content:` tells it what to place in the popover. In this case, I just made a function that grabs the html content of the `pop-inn` div.  (The content option needs to use a function to return html, or you get an error).

Hope this helps!

```js
$(function () {
  $(".pop-show").popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: "focus",
    content: function() {
      return $('.pop-inn').html();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<a class="pop-show btn btn-primary" tabindex="0" type="button" style="margin:100px;" data-toggle="popover" title="Your Popover Title" data-content="">Show</a>

<div class="pop-inn" style="display:none;">
    <p>content</p>
    <h5><img src="img.png" alt="image">Candidate</h5>
</div>
```